# Multiple css dropdown menus appearing at the same place and position

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on multiple css dropdown menu and the problem is in the position that the menus appear . AS you can see , Shop menu is in its own position but the services menu appears just in the same position as the shop menu was before. I'm new to front-end web development so anyone can help me to fix this please?

```css
*{
    margin: auto;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    direction: ltr;
    background-color: gold;
    padding: 15px;
}

.primaryHeaderMenu ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    background-color: lightslategrey;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.primaryHeaderMenu ul li ul li{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.primaryHeaderMenu ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

.primaryItems{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.primaryHeaderMenu li a{
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.secondaryHeaderMenu li a{
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.primaryHeaderMenu{
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.secondaryHeaderMenu li{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <title>Irancell</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="irancellLogo">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="/iracell_logo.png" alt="Irancell" width="60px" height="60px">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="primaryHeaderMenu">
            <ul>
                <li class="primaryItems"><a href="#">Shop</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">ُSimcards</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Packages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Devices</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Methods</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="primaryItems"><a href="#">Services</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HighSpeed Net</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Applications</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Conversation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Messaging</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="primaryItems"><a href="#">Festivals</a></li>
                <li class="primaryItems"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                <li class="primaryItems"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="primaryItems"><a href="#">Cooperation</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="secondaryHeaderMenu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="/search.png" alt="Search">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try adding: `position: relative;` to `.primaryItems` and `left: 0;` to `.primaryHeaderMenu ul li ul`

Comment: Apart from fixing it yourself I would also highly recommend checking out [Bootstrap's Nav Bar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) since you mentioned that you are new to front-end dev.

Comment: @BjørnNyborg It worked , thank you , Can you explain me what was wrong and how did you fix it?

Comment: @LukeGalea Sure , thanks

Comment: When you position something with `absolute`, it will be positioned depending on the nearest non-static positioned element. So if you want to dropdowns to be placed depending on the `.primaryItems`, you need to add a position for these.

The `left:0;` means that they will be placed 0px from the left side of the closest "non-static positioned element", in this case the parent `.primaryItems`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `.primaryItems` class. Then add `left: 0;` to your `.primaryHeaderMenu ul li ul` class. The issue is `position: absolute;` is hoisting it's self up to the first relative positioned element in the HTML DOM, then they overlap each other since they have the same parent with the same position. [There are interactive examples of this on W3Cschools.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp.)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following is useful for you.

Try replacing

```
.primaryItems {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

with

```
.primaryItems {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: relative; // New Line
}
```

and

try replacing

```
.primaryHeaderMenu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    background-color: lightslategrey;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

with

```
.primaryHeaderMenu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    background-color: lightslategrey;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0; // New Line
}
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/BaLNvBN